# A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H in the matrix, provided that they use the letters at a maximum and a minimum of 2 times

Tags: java

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHN6j.png)

like this ...

As shown in the picture, 3 letters of the same letter should be written at most and at least 2 times.

this is my pillow code part

```
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++){
    for (int j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++){
        char c = (char)(r.nextInt(8) + 'a');
        cards[i][j] = new Card(c);
    }
}
```

In a 4x4 card game we were trying to find the same 2 letters written under the cards.

Comment: can you please translate the question

Comment: I fixed it, I missed it sorry

Comment: what is ```Card()``` and what do you exactly want to achieve, please provide the complete question

Comment: Are you aware of the concept of shuffling? It allows to create a non-random list of required entries and bring them into a random order.

Comment: What is your question? See [ask].

Comment: I use private getter setter as guess and value in my card class.Question is Card Game If If you examine the picture, see each point of the matrix as a card and put random letters under the cards. Then I try to find the same letters by opening the letters at those points with the help of the keyboard and i use translate I'm sorry if there is a mistake

Comment: All I need is to try to write randomly generated letters in my code block at least and at most 2 times. I can randomly generate letters and place them in the matrix, but I cannot control the number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the `Random` class at all.  As @Yunnosch mentioned in his comment, you need to create an array of letter pairs, copy the array to a `java.util.List`, shuffle the `List`, and copy the shuffled `List` to your matrix.

Here's the output from a test run.

```
[b, e, e, b]
[g, d, f, d]
[f, h, h, a]
[c, g, a, c]
```

Here's the code I used.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class ShuffleExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] cards = new char[4][4];

        char[] letters = { 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 
                'e', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'g', 'g', 'h', 'h' };
        List<Character> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
            pairs.add(letters[i]);
        }
        
        Collections.shuffle(pairs);

        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cards[i].length; j++) {
                cards[i][j] = pairs.get(index++);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cards[i]));
        }
    }

}
```